# Through polymorphism. How I can get the expected response by calling a method of base class?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class Class1(object):

    def say_my_name(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        print 'I am a class1'

    def how_are_you(self):
        print 'how are you from class1'
        self.say_my_name()


class Class2(Class1):

    def say_my_name(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        print 'I am a class2'

    def how_are_you(self):
        print 'how are you from class2'
        self.say_my_name()

# all right
c1 = Class1()
c2 = Class2()
c1.how_are_you()
c2.how_are_you()

# attempt one. I expect 'I am a class1' but I get 'I am a class2'
c3 = super(Class2, c2)
c3.how_are_you() # 

# attempt two. I expect 'I am a class1' but I get 'I am a class2'
Class1.how_are_you(c2)
```

As you can see in my test code.

I expected that after obtaining, through polymorphism, a reference to the base class that a call to method `how_are_you()` return **I am a class1** but I get **I am a class2**

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 12/06/2016 15:47**

A more realistic example

```
class Sheet(object):

    def mergeArrayInColumns(self, startRow, startColumn, dimRows, dimColumns, separator=None):
        # bla, bla, bla...
        return True

    def mergeColumns(self, startColumn, columns, separator=None):
        self.mergeArrayInColumns(0, startColumn, self.rowCount(), columns, separator)


class CommandMergeColumns(QUndoSelectionCommand):

    def __init__(self, sheet, startRow, rows, separator, undoSelection, redoSelection):
        description = 'merge {} rows at [{},:]'.format(rows, startRow)
        super(CommandMergeColumns, self).__init__(description, undoSelection, redoSelection)
        # get a base class?!
        self.sheet = super(CommandSheet, sheet)
        self.startRow = startRow
        self.rows = rows
        self.separator = separator

    def redo(self):
        self.redoArray = self.sheet.getArray(self.startRow, 0, self.rows, self.sheet.columnCount())
        # the problem it's here
        self.sheet.mergeColumns(self.startRow, self.rows, self.separator)
        # with this work but I do not like solution 
        #self.sheet.mergeArrayInColumns(self.startRow,
        #                            0,
        #                            self.rows,
        #                            self.sheet.columnCount(),
        #                            self.separator)

    def undo(self):
        self.sheet.removeColumns(self.startRow, 1)
        self.sheet.insertColumns(self.startRow, self.redoArray)


class CommandSheet(QObject, Sheet):

    def mergeColumns(self, startColumn, columns, separator, undoSelection, redoSelection):
        command = CommandMergeColumns(self, startColumn, columns, separator, undoSelection, redoSelection)
        self.stack.push(command)

# and finally I call mergeColumns method...
document = CommandSheet()
document.mergeColumns(startColumn, count, None, undoSelection, redoSelection)
```

Comment: Note that using `super(self.__class__, self)` is a bad idea. Use `super(ThisClass, self)` instead.

Comment: If I change `super(self.__class__, self)` by `super(ThisClass, self)` the output is the same.

Comment: Yes, that's why it's just a comment. However, note that explicitly calling a specific version of `how_are_you` does not change where the MRO will start looking for `self.say_my_name`, which is on the instance you've explicitly passed in as `self` (`c2`, an instance of `Class2`, in both cases). Try `super(Class2, c2).say_my_name()` instead.

Comment: Yes. That's solution I apply now. But it's not elegant. This solution means knowing that `how_are_you()` makes an internal call to `say_my_name()` and also in my real solution `how_are_you()` has more code that the call to `say_my_name()`

Comment: Then it seems like you are approaching this in the wrong way. Why do you need to manually intervene in the MRO at all? Could you give a less abstract example? Please [edit] accordingly, otherwise we risk solving [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731).

Comment: I recommend that you read this article on using `super()`: https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: Maybe I need a new approach in my class hierarchy. I'll think about it. Any help is welcome ;)